# Potty Training while on vacation- Help

Tags: toddler, potty-training, travel

My almost 3-year-old has done a complete 180 since my last potty training question 2 weeks ago. We decided to try the barebum method where she's nude, then commando, then with underwear over the course of a week, and it clicked right away on day 1.

Here is what has changed:

- I no longer have to encourage to go to the restroom. With the exception of when we are going for a drive, I tell her to go before we leave and also right before bed.
- She has been going alone and wants privacy
- Her pull-ups have been dry all night for the past 4-5 days, so I think we will switch to underwear at night and waterproof sheets
- She has had an accident about once a week when she's too distracted and doesn't make it to the restroom on time.

Question:
Since we've been in lockdown, we really haven't had to deal with accidents in public or public bathroom sagas. We are planning on staying the summer in a different state to quarantine there for a few unrelated reasons, however, is it possible that she will regress there due to the change in environment?
How do other parents work on potty training while traveling or navigating normal outside of home life?

Comment: Do you have control over the space you're in?  I.e., if you want to go back to nude or whatever, can you?  Or will the messes from that be impractical to deal with (due to being in a space you can't control, or in a space that's impractical to clean)?  If you're at Grandma's, do you have their buyin?

Comment: Yup we should be able to control the space since it is family, they will understand and hopefully be able to help!

Comment: I always had an "emergency box" of spare clothes in the car, originally for toilet training accidents it then grew to be spares for "they fell in the puddle, river" etc... an old power drill box fits under the seat in most cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anytime there's a change in routine, it can be expected that a regression can occur. This would hold true even if you weren't traveling, but simply getting back to a regular routine of school/work, activities and home. Also there are a lot more distractions out and about than at home where everything is status quo.

I would set a little reminder on your phone for every 2 hours or so to mention it to her and see if she needs to go. I think you'll know really early on if she's going to transition well or need more nudges to go.

My son never needed the nudges, but also during his potty training phase there was a lot of extended consistency in a school and home environment.

Comment: Thank you! if she does regress, do you think I should start back at step zero (bare bum)?

Comment: Probably not necessary for her, it sounds like she took to it really quickly. A few bare bum days at home though never hurt anyone!